# the .htaccess is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to write a simple `.htaccess` rule to change

```
https://webxxx.example.net/~test/id/123
```

to

```
https://webxxx.example.net/~test/show.php?id=123
```

But

```
https://webxxx.example.net/~test/id/123
```

is now redirected to my 404 page not found.

my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^\/?~test\/id\/(\w+)$ /~test/show.php?hash=$1
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: What is `~test`? Is it reference to `public_html` of `test` user account?

Comment: You must be sure the `.htaccess` is enabled in apache config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution:

don't need match the reference of public_html folder in regular expression, only in replace

```
RewriteEngine onRewriteRule ^id\/(\w+)$ /~test/show.php?hash=$1
```

thanks to all :)

Answer (score 1):

where is the .htaccess placed ? is it under the main root ? or is it under the subfolder (subdomain) ... try to change the place of the .htaccess and make sure it is under the specific subdomain area .

Comment: the 'domain.net' on this url is an reference for myhosting.com.
the .htaccess is in public_html folder

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^id\/([0-9]*)$ /~test/show.php?id=$1
```

This will just accept numbers after the id.